# Unable to find pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am not able to locate or view the pg_hba.conf file.I logged into postgres as superuser and did the following

```
postgres=# show hba_file;
               hba_file               
--------------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# cd /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
postgres-#
```

I don't see anything. Does anybody have any idea why??

Thanks

Comment: `cd` is an operating system command, you have to leave the `psql` tool in order to run `cd`. Additionally: it's a **file** not a directory, so you can't "cd" into it to begin with. You need to open it with an editor.

Comment: Thanks. I used the above command because I saw it in one of the answers in another thread. I left ```psql``` and entered the command ```nano /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf``` but I am getting the error message  
```[ Directory '/var/lib/postgresql/data' does not exist ]```. So how do I access the pg_hba.conf file??

Comment: cd to that directory first. Confirm the file is there, it should be, then vim into it?

Comment: How do I cd into it? I tried this but it didn't work 
`inshaf@anubis:~$ cd /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`
`bash: cd: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory`
Is there anything else I should do??

Comment: Yes read the answers provided e.g. From  @a_horse_with_no_name; 'Additionally: it's a file not a directory, so you can't "cd" into it to begin with'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver : I typed `inshaf@anubis:~$ nano /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf ` and I got back `[ Directory '/var/lib/postgresql/data' does not exist ]`. I typed `inshaf@anubis:~$ vim /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf` and I got back `"/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" [New DIRECTORY] `. So I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is the pg_hba.conf file even there?? After typing in both commands I just see empty screens.

Comment: Probably because this requires superuser permissions trying add `sudo` to beginning of commans e.g. `sudo vim ...`. You will be prompted for password, use your OS user password.  It would help to know OS and version as well as how you installed Postgres? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver :  I am using postgres 12.9 in ubuntu 20.04. `psql (12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1))`. Even after having typed `inshaf@anubis:~$ sudo vim /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf` I am getting an empty screen with this message at the bottom `"/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" [New DIRECTORY] `. I don't see anything else pretty much.

Comment: You have a `docker` tag, is the Postgres server running inside a Docker container?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver : Yes it's running inside a docker container. Does that make any difference???

Comment: Yes, because I'm guessing you trying to open the file in the host OS file system and the file is actually in the container file system.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver : Oh Ok!! Do you know how I can open from inside the docker container?? What the commands are for e.g??

Comment: No, I don't use Docker.

Answer (score 0):

**To find & edit the pg_hba.conf file:**

```
sudo psql -U postgres -c 'show hba_file'
```

It'll display the location of the file. Simply copy that and exit the psql terminal.
Paste the address after "sudo nano" like this:

```
sudo nano /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Remember to restart you database service afterwards.